# Anyone know how to make an entire form disappear on a jsp page?

Tags: forms, jsp

```
<H1 align="center">ID Lookup</H1>
<FORM ACTION="index.jsp" METHOD="POST">

<H3 ALIGN="center">Please enter your User ID:</H3>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="userIDTextBox">

<br>
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
<%
    String userID = request.getParameter("userIDTextBox");

%>
</FORM>
```

I'm a beginner and this is my form on my jsp page. What I want to do is have the form disappear after submitting. Can anyone help me please? Or give some tips?

Comment: Which materials did you use to start learning HTML and JSP? The presence of those uppercased HTML tag/attribute format, the since 1998 deprecated `align` attribute, and the old school JSP *scriptlet* suggests that it's more than a decade old. This is not right. I strongly recommend to catch up with most recent materials. A good starting point is our tag wiki page. Hover the `[jsp]` tag which you put on the question until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Comment: As to your concrete question, just conditionally print HTML using an `if` block (or tag, if you want to be modern). If the condition in the `if` block/tag is not matched, then its body won't be executed. Makes sense, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your form an ID, then use a javascript command to get your form element and set its visibility.

```
var myform = document.getElementById('myForm');
myform.style.visibility="hidden";
```

Now you just need to handle a javascript event and run that.

Answer (score 0):

After Reading your requirement all I understand is you are trying to read parameter `"userIDTextBox"` from one page and need to display the value to some other page. And You are trying to achieve the same in one page.

Rather have two separate pages..

1. First with Form and required text field
2. Other to display the value
3. Define **servlet** and **servlet-mapping** configuration in **web.xml**

That is the valid way to do it. Hope it may help